# Pycharm / github update not uploading all files

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I've utilized pycharm and git / github for sometime now to keep my code co-ordinated between a few pc's i'm using to develop.  Presently, though, I've got an issue that I can't resolve:  I downloaded a github repository and renamed it to save it under a new project name.  When I perform the commits / pushes on this latest project, however, the only files i see in the github repository are an '.idea' folder and some .xml files within that folder.  None of those are part of my project .py files which i keep in a src_code sub-folder.

I've tried to reference pycharm documentation regarding how to add files to my project, but i'm not finding anything that has helped me sort it out successfully.

thanks

Comment: What is "a github instance"?

Comment: A repository.  edited my post.

Comment: Are you `push` after your `commit`?

Comment: I do yes.  But it only pushes the files i described in my question.  thank you.